# How to call HTTP Request from React PWA?

Tags: reactjs, http, progressive-web-apps

pwa
I am developing an React Progressive Web App(PWA). I want to call http (not secured host) get request. How to call this? Can anybody help me on this please?

Comment: I think that you would like to know if is possible to make a request for not secure host instead of https hosts. Am I right?

Comment: Have you tried to use a service worker for intercepting HTTP/HTTPS requests so your app can decide what gets served from a cache, the local data store, or the network?